# smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully

Tags: azure, office365

File "C:\Users\SanketPatil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 655, in auth
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [PN2PR01CA0009.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')

Process finished with exit code 1

I have enabled SMTP auth too

Answer (score 1):

Issue is related to some security enablement's or opening of ports related. You may try the below steps and try accessing. If it is working, then it can be confirmed related to default security and enable the required security features and re enable the security defaults.

- Firstly login into to Azure portal
- Click on  `Azure Active Directory`
- Then click on`Properties`.
- Then Click on `Manage security defaults`.
- Now make  `Enable security defaults`  =`No`.
- Now click on `Save` button

[image]

***Taken References from:***

[Fix issues with printers, scanners, and LOB applications that send email using Microsoft 365 or Office 365 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/fix-issues-with-printers-scanners-and-lob-applications-that-send-email-using-off#error-authentication-unsuccessful)

Answer (score 0):

Еhere may be two possible causes of this issue. These settings would block Legacy Authentication:

[image: These settings would block Legacy Authentication.]