# Changes to default security settings for Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, authentication

Does anyone know what the new changes to the default security settings on Azure are?

I have a web application through which I was sending emails using a Microsoft account with 2FA and an app password. The SMTP for the mail account were enabled.

There seem to be some updates to the default security settings due to which the emails were no longer sending and I was getting the following error -
**535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully.**

Upon searching for this error above, I found that most people solved it by enabling SMTP on the email account, however, this was already enabled for me.

I then disabled the default tenant security settings for my organization and the emails have started working again.

I am not sure if that is the best implementation and what the unintended consequences would be of disabling these settings. if anyone can share any more information on this it would be much appreciated. Happy to share any more details as required.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72782240/smtplib-smtpauthenticationerror-535-b5-7-139-authentication-unsuccessful-th   


I implemented the solution in point 3 of the answer to this question. But wondering what the consequences of disabling the default security is.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that, **`SMTP`** protocol comes under **Legacy Authentication** protocols.

Enabling Security Defaults will **block** legacy authentication that can't do MFA, which is the reason behind getting the error like below:

> **Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully.**

To resolve the error, you need to disable security defaults like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Properties -> Manage Security Defaults***

[image]

***The consequences of disabling security defaults are:***

- Security risks like identity-related attacks (password spray, replay, and phishing) are more often on user accounts using legacy authentication.
- Your user accounts won't get prompts to configure MFA while signing in to Azure.
- Users with admin role can directly login to Azure without MFA.
- No longer send MFA prompts to vulnerable user accounts (signed-in with new device from different location).

To avoid all these, make sure to **configure conditional access policy** that enables MFA, if security defaults are disabled.

According to this **[MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business-premium/m365bp-conditional-access?view=o365-worldwide#conditional-access),**

> You can use either security defaults or Conditional Access policies, but **you can't use both at the same time**.

So, make sure to **turn off security defaults** if you are using conditional access policies.

For more in detail, please find below **reference**:

[**Azure Active Directory security defaults   | Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults)